# IntentFilter Camera and Picture Taken

Tags: android, camera, media

So my question is to know if there is an Action/BroadCast when a picture is taken with Camera , and if there is a way to get the File Name of the new Created File(Picture) ? ,

Thanks .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Intent filter for knowing about new picture taken:

```
<intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.hardware.action.NEW_PICTURE" />
            </intent-filter>
```

Comment: Great , Thanks you , and we get the file Name/Path with the Uri ?

Comment: Sorry, Don't know about that. :(

Answer (score 1):

There are two ways controlling the camera.

- Start an intend that will bring up the default camera activity and
  receive the image using the onResult() function. The intent will return the picture.
- Controll the camera, including the preview image, by your app (I
  wouldn't recommend this for the beginning).

The easy way is VERY easy:

```
private void dispatchTakePictureIntent(int actionCode) {
Intent takePictureIntent = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
startActivityForResult(takePictureIntent, actionCode);
```

}

The second is very nasty.
We're talking about dealing with memory exceptions, problems initializing the camera and so on.

Google has a bunch of documentations and tutorials about this.

Easy: 
http://developer.android.com/training/camera/index.html (Capturing Photos)

Advanced:
http://developer.android.com/training/camera/cameradirect.html

I remember when I implemented the easy way, the camera wouldn't start a second intent. Also there was an issue about the image quality but I was able to handle all of this.

I'm going to post some code to avoid this later on.

Enjoy.